# How can I deploy my angular 2 app on tomcat or jboss?

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, jboss, angular, openshift

I have built a basic angular 2 app. However I need to deploy it on Jboss or Tomcat as I need to use it along with my Java EE application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a bundler such as `angular-cli` or `webpack` to create the production bundle which is then served by the HTTP server. The bundler creates all required file that go into the `htdocs` directory. Normally Angular apps are completely decoupled from your backend server so there shouldn't be any JBoss or Tomcat specifics.

The Angular team are going to increasingly focus on `angular-cli` as the premier bundling solution so it might be a good idea to start there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *angular-cli* you can use *ng build* command. It creates all static files for deploy Angular2 app into the **dist** folder. You must copy and paste them in **webresources** folder of your Web Application (WAR). At the moment I am looking for how to deploy this files easier.